# Define a hashset with customized key

Tags: c#, key, hashset

I need to define hashset which key is MyClass

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string m_x;
    private string m_y;
    MyClass(string x,string y)
    {
       m_x = x;
       m_y =y;
    }
}
```

So I have

```
HashSet <MyClass> myHash;
MyClass m = new MyClass("1","123");
myHash.Add(m);
bool isContained = myHash.Contains(m);
```

`IsContained` is `false`....What is wrong?
what could be another container, which allows to save the unique keys? and return the answer if key is inside with minimum complexity?

Comment: Can you show the actual code? This should throw a NRE.

Comment: Override *GetHashCode* and *Equals*

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine for me. Can you post a code which reproduces the behavior ?

Comment: Does `HashSet<MyClass> myHash = new HashSet<MyClass>();` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** Assuming you don't want to compare the objects by their *references*,  you should override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods of `MyClass`

```
HashSet<MyClass> myHash = new HashSet<MyClass>();
MyClass m1 = new MyClass("1", "123");
MyClass m2 = new MyClass("1", "123");
myHash.Add(m1);
bool b = myHash.Contains(m2); //true
```

---

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string m_x;
    private string m_y;
    public MyClass(string x, string y)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return m_x.GetHashCode() ^ m_y.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        var other = obj as MyClass;
        return m_x == other.m_x && m_y == other.m_y;
    }
}
```

**b)** You can also use IEqualityComparer to compare your objects, But in this case you need some public properties

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string m_x;
    public string m_y;
    public MyClass(string x, string y)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }
}

public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{

    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        return x.m_x == y.m_x && x.m_y == y.m_y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
    {
        return obj.m_x.GetHashCode() ^ obj.m_y.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now, you only need to give the comparer to the HashSet's constructor

```
HashSet<MyClass> myHash = new HashSet<MyClass>( new MyEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your MyClass so it implements Equals and GetHashCode:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string m_x;
    private string m_y;

    public MyClass(string x, string y)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var typed = obj as MyClass;
        if (typed == null) return false;
        return typed.m_x == m_x && typed.m_y ==m_y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return new {m_x, m_y}.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now the IsContained2 also is true, even if it has not been added to the HashSet:

```
HashSet<MyClass> myHash =new HashSet<MyClass>();
MyClass m = new MyClass("1", "123");
MyClass m2 = new MyClass("1", "123");
myHash.Add(m);
bool isContained = myHash.Contains(m);
bool isContained2 = myHash.Contains(m2); // True!
```